# Having problem with Array of objects using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a website for my personal use, to give me my semester schedule and the section that I should take of each course, so I started with building some `classes`

and My first class to build was `Section` class to store the information of each section:

```
// This is the ES6 method to share the class with other files to use it there.
// export default Course;

import { Section } from "../js/Classes/Section.js";

/**
 * Represents a university course section.
 *
 * @class
 */
class Section {
    /**
     * Creates a new Section instance.
     *
     * @param {string} sectionNumber - The number of the section.
     * @param {string} startTime - The start time of the section in "hh:mm AM/PM" format.
     * @param {string} finishTime - The finish time of the section in "hh:mm AM/PM" format.
     * @param {(string|string[])} day - The day(s) on which the section occurs. Can be a single day (e.g., "Monday") or an array of days (e.g., ["Sunday", "Tuesday"]).
     * @param {string} mode - The mode of the course. Can be "Online", "Offline", or "Blended".
     * @param {string} type - The type of the course. Can be "Sunday-Tuesday-Thursday", "Monday-Wednesday", or "Lab".
     */
    constructor(sectionNumber, startTime, finishTime, day, mode, type) {
        this.sectionNumber = sectionNumber;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.finishTime = finishTime;
        this.day = day;
        this.mode = mode;
        this.type = type;
    }

    /**
     * Accessor Properties (Getters and Setters) for the class.
     *
     * These accessors allow interaction with class properties as if accessing direct attributes.
     * For instance, use `instanceOfClass.startTime` to retrieve or set values instead of invoking a method.
     * Such design, where getters and setters are accessed like regular properties without parentheses,
     * is commonly known as "accessor properties" or "accessor methods".
     */

    /**
     * Sets the section number.
     *
     * @param {string} sectionNumber - The number of the section to set.
     */
    set sectionNumber(sectionNumber) {
        if (typeof sectionNumber !== "string") {
            throw new Error(
                `INVALID INPUT for sectionNumber '${sectionNumber}': It must be a string!`
            );
        }
        if (sectionNumber) this._sectionNumber = sectionNumber;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the section number.
     *
     * @returns {number} - The section number.
     */
    get sectionNumber() {
        return this._sectionNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the start time of the section.
     *
     * @param {string} startTime - The start time in "hh:mm AM/PM" format.
     */
    set startTime(startTime) {
        if (!this.isValidStartTime(startTime)) {
            throw new Error(
                `INVALID INPUT for startTime '${startTime}': Invalid format. Expected HH:MM format.`
            );
        }
        this._startTime = startTime;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the start time of the section.
     *
     * @returns {string} - The start time in "hh:mm AM/PM" format.
     */
    get startTime() {
        return this._startTime;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the finish time of the section.
     *
     * @param {string} finishTime - The finish time in "hh:mm AM/PM" format.
     */
    set finishTime(finishTime) {
        if (!this.isValidFinishTime(finishTime)) {
            throw new Error(
                `INVALID INPUT for finishTime '${finishTime}': Invalid format. Expected HH:MM format.`
            );
        }
        this._finishTime = finishTime;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the finish time of the section.
     *
     * @returns {string} - The finish time in "hh:mm AM/PM" format.
     */
    get finishTime() {
        return this._finishTime;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the day(s) of the section.
     *
     * @param {(string|string[])} day - The day(s) to set. Can be a single day (e.g., "Monday") or an array of days (e.g., ["Sunday", "Tuesday"]).
     */
    set day(day) {
        const validDays = [
            "Sunday",
            "Monday",
            "Tuesday",
            "Wednesday",
            "Thursday",
            "Friday",
            "Saturday",
            "Sunday-Tuesday-Thursday",
            "Monday-Wednesday",
        ];

        if (typeof day === "string") {
            if (!validDays.includes(day)) {
                throw new Error(
                    `Invalid day provided for section ${this._sectionNumber}. It should be one of Sunday, Monday, ... Saturday, Sunday-Tuesday-Thursday, Monday-Wednesday. Received: ${day}`
                );
            }
            this._day = day;
        } else if (Array.isArray(day)) {
            for (const d of day) {
                if (!validDays.includes(d)) {
                    throw new Error(
                        `Invalid day provided in array for section ${this._sectionNumber}. It should be one of Sunday, Monday, ... Saturday. Received: ${d}`
                    );
                }
            }
            this._day = day;
        } else {
            throw new Error(
                `Day for section ${
                    this._sectionNumber
                } should be a string or an array of strings. Received: ${typeof day}`
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the day(s) of the section.
     *
     * @returns {(string|string[])} - The day(s) of the section.
     */
    get day() {
        return this._day;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the mode of the section.
     *
     * @param {string} mode - The mode to set. Must be one of "Online", "Offline", "Blended".
     */
    set mode(mode) {
        const validModes = ["Online", "Offline", "Blended"];
        if (!validModes.includes(mode)) {
            throw new Error(
                `Invalid mode provided for section ${this._sectionNumber}. It should be one of Online, Offline, or Blended. Received: ${mode}`
            );
        }
        this._mode = mode;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the mode of the section.
     *
     * @returns {string} - The mode of the section.
     */
    get mode() {
        return this._mode;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the type of the section.
     *
     * @param {string} type - The type to set. Must be one of "Sunday-Tuesday-Thursday", "Monday-Wednesday", "Lab".
     */
    set type(type) {
        const validTypes = ["Sunday-Tuesday-Thursday", "Monday-Wednesday", "Lab"];
        if (!validTypes.includes(type)) {
            throw new Error(
                `Invalid type '${type}' provided for section number ${this._sectionNumber}. It should be one of Sunday-Tuesday-Thursday, Monday-Wednesday, Lab.`
            );
        }
        this._type = type;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the type of the section.
     *
     * @returns {string} - The type of the section.
     */
    get type() {
        return this._type;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if a given time string adheres to the "HH:mm" format and has valid hour and minute values.
     *
     * @param {string} timeString - The time string to validate in the "HH:mm" format.
     * @returns {boolean} True if the time string is valid; otherwise, false.
     */
    isValidStartTime(startTimeString) {
        const timePattern = /^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/;
        return timePattern.test(startTimeString);
    }

    /**
     * Checks if a given finish time string adheres to the "HH:mm" format and has valid hour and minute values.
     *
     * @param {string} finishTimeString - The finish time string to validate in the "HH:mm" format.
     * @returns {boolean} True if the finish time string is valid; otherwise, false.
     */
    isValidFinishTime(finishTimeString) {
        const timePattern = /^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/;
        return timePattern.test(finishTimeString);
    }
}

// Also this line to let you import the class in other parts
// of the code and other files to use it there.
export default Section;
```

Then I started building the second `class` which is `Course` class, so I can store the `name` of the course and the `array of sections` for that course!
And this is the class:

```
// import { Course } from "../js/Classes/Course";

/**
 * This Course class is used to create object for each course
 * and we store the Name of each course and an array of the section of that course!
 *
 */
import { Section } from "./Section";

class Course {
    constructor(courseName, ...sections) {
        this.name(courseName);
        this.sections(...sections);
    }

    // Setters for the class attributes
    set name(courseName) {
        if (typeof courseName !== "string") {
            throw new Error(
                `INVALID INPUT: Expected a string for course name but received ${typeof courseName}. Value: ${courseName}`
            );
        }
        this._name = courseName;
    }

    // Getters for the class attributes
    get name() {
        return this._name;
    }

    /**
     * This setter check if the parameter is array!
     * then it checks if each element of the array is an instance of
     * Section class!
     */
    set sections(sections) {
        if (!Array.isArray(sections)) {
            throw new Error(
                `INVALID INPUT: Expected an array for sections but received ${typeof sections}. Value: ${sections}`
            );
        }

        // Validate that each section in the array is an instance of Section
        for (const section of sections) {
            if (!(section instanceof Section)) {
                throw new Error(
                    `INVALID INPUT: Expected an instance of Section but received ${typeof section}. Value: ${section}`
                );
            }
        }
        this._sections = sections;
    }

    /**
     * This function returns the array of sections
     * for this course that is calling the function!
     */
    get sections() {
        return this._sections;
    }
}

// This is the ES6 method to share the class with other files to use it there.
export default Course;
```

Then I wanted to test those classes so I wrote some test cases you can see here:

```
// Create some sample sections
const section1 = new Section(
    "1",
    "08:00",
    "09:30",
    "Monday-Wednesday",
    "Online",
    "Monday-Wednesday"
);
const section2 = new Section(
    "2",
    "09:00",
    "10:30",
    "Monday-Wednesday",
    "Offline",
    "Monday-Wednesday"
);
const section3 = new Section(
    "3",
    "11:00",
    "12:00",
    "Sunday-Tuesday-Thursday",
    "Blended",
    "Sunday-Tuesday-Thursday"
);
const section4 = new Section(
    "4",
    "12:00",
    "13:30",
    "Monday-Wednesday",
    "Offline",
    "Monday-Wednesday"
);
const section5 = new Section(
    "5",
    "14:00",
    "15:00",
    "Thursday",
    "Offline",
    "Lab"
);

// Create additional blended sections
const blendedSection1 = new Section(
    "6",
    "10:00",
    "11:30",
    "Monday",
    "Blended",
    "Monday-Wednesday"
); // Monday in-person
const blendedSection2 = new Section(
    "7",
    "12:00",
    "13:30",
    "Wednesday",
    "Blended",
    "Monday-Wednesday"
); // Wednesday in-person

// Create some sample courses with the above sections
const course1 = new Course("Course1", [section1, section2]);
const course2 = new Course("Course2", [section3]);
const course3 = new Course("Course3", [section4, section5]);
const blendedCourse = new Course("BlendedCourse", [
    blendedSection1,
    blendedSection2,
]);

// Create an array of these sample courses
const sampleCourses = [course1, course2, course3, blendedCourse];
```

and I have added some proper `Error Messages` to each `setter` in both classes, and I keep getting this Error Message that I wrote:

> Error: INVALID INPUT: Expected an instance of Section but received object. Value: [{"_sectionNumber":"1","_startTime":"08:00","_finishTime":"09:30","_day":"Monday-Wednesday","_mode":"Online","_type":"Monday-Wednesday"},{"_sectionNumber":"2","_startTime":"09:00","_finishTime":"10:30","_day":"Monday-Wednesday","_mode":"Offline","_type":"Monday-Wednesday"}]

So the problem here that in my class `Course` I am checking in the array of `Sections` setter I am checking if all of the instances in the array is objects of type `Section`, and if not give me message error that is above. And I can't know why is this happening because I created all the objects using the same class constructor.

I am new to JS and I had that idea of making something to help me instead of spending time in choosing the good sections for my college semester schedule.

Comment: You shouldn't have `import { Section }` in the file that defines the `Section` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Course` constructor should assign to `this.name` and `this.sections`. This will be converted automatically into calls to the setters, you don't write them as method calls.

```
class Course {
  constructor(courseName, ...sections) {
    this.name = courseName;
    this.sections = sections;
  }

  // ...
}
```

The `Course` constructor expects the sections to be separate arguments, since it uses `...sections` in the parameter list. So you shouldn't make an array when calling `new Course()`. Change

```
const course1 = new Course("Course1", [section1, section2]);
```

to

```
const course1 = new Course("Course1", section1, section2);
```